# junit test cases for this custom reader

Tags: java, junit, spring-batch

I am new in writing junit test cases.

I have one custom item reader ,which is reading files from directory and returning pojo. Can you plz tell me how to write junit test cases for this custom reader.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as any junit test: you create your custom item reader, you call its method, and you check that it returns the right thing. What's the concrete problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can test individual step independently. Reader,processor and writer will be tested.

Reference code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { YourConfig.class })
public classSampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;


 @setup 
 public void setup()
 {
    // do setup needed for your setp 
 }



    @Test
    public void testStep() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("yourStep");

        Assert.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you should finalize the scope of your unit test & know that unit test for a Spring batch reader are no different than that of any regular Java class.

1. if test scope includes reading & verifying actual file data then you need to take care of that in code so that your tests don't fail anywhere i.e. you should modify logic in reader to something like ,

   A. You keep a unit test file on classpath & some kind of flag that can be set from outside to know if read has to happen from claspath or disk

   B. You can make your reader configurable enough to set file location from either classpath or disk then from your unit tests , you set file path to be classpath.

   Eventually, what I am trying to say is that - Don't write your unit tests which will work on files from disk or any other external source.
2. If unit test scope is not about reading & verifying an actual file , you can simply encapsulate that part in some kind of service & inject as dependency in reader and mock it using some mocking framework.

Rest would be to construct an instance of reader and call `read()` method.

Answer by Niraj can be used to do overall job testing & individual step tests and I wouldn't call that a unit test for reader reading data from files.